# What is the recommended method to create custom Javascript/Angular functions using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, function, angularjs-directive

In my project I have several JavaScript utility functions - some do things like text parsing, others present some UI components.

I understand that DOM type manipulation is to be handled by directives.  However I have created factories that allow me to call elements by name.

I'm wondering if the same method is recommended for global or even local function utility libraries.

```
// Angular factory containing custom functions
// Technically, any DOM manipulation should be handled 
app.factory('customUIFunctions', function () {
    return {
        showError: function (title, content) {
            $.bigBox({
                title: title,
                content: content == null ? "An error occurred.<br /><br />If this error persists, please contact support." : content,
                color: "#C46A69",
                icon: "fa fa-warning shake animated",
                //number: "1",
                timeout: 10000  // 10 second timeout
            });
        }, . . .
```

And custom non-UI-related functions:

```
app.factory('customFunctions', function () {
    return {
        getUrlFriendlyText: function (text) {
            return "formatted: " + text;
        },
        someFunction: function () {

        }
    };
});
```

In the latter, `customFunctions` would be injected into a script; usage:

```
var foo = customFunctions.getUrlFriendlyText("sometext")
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: if it works for you, go with it. i don't see the need to tie every little part of an app into angular, but it probably doesn't harm project maintenance or performance to do so. I prefer plain objects with callable methods for utils, much like window.Math, because they transport across projects independent of frameworks or libraries, but that's me and my general values/needs talking louder than the specific goals or wiring of a given project.

Comment: Looks fine. Some may say not to use jQuery in a service, but I know at least one expert / trainer that does. John Papa creates a `logger` service with a bunch of different UI alerts. It uses his toastr library, which depends no jQuery.